# Can I move 256-bit from memory location immediately to YMM registers?

Tags: avx, sse2

Can I move 256-bit from memory location immediately to YMM registers? 
If I want to fill an xmm register, I use in inline asm in gcc:

```
          "movlpd mytest_1(%rip),%xmm1 \n\t"
          "movhpd mytest_1+8(%rip),%xmm1 \n\t"
```

Can this be made easier I guess?

Furthermore:
The same procedure move aligned or not 4 quadwords in 1 step to Ymm0?
I look for the reverse of Vmovdqa ymm1, mem256 source -> destination.

Comment: That sequence is *never* optimal.  On some (very old non-AVX) CPUs, doing two 8B loads is useful on data that's 8B-aligned but not 16B aligned.  But starting with `movlpd` gives you a false dependency on the old value of xmm1, while `movsd` is a 64-bit load that zeros the upper half, so the resulting `xmm1` has no dependency on the old value.  If you had a CPU with only SSE1 but not SSE2 support, then you might have to use `movlps`, but `movlpd` already requires SSE2 (and takes 1 extra byte of machine code than `movlpd`).

Answer (score 3):

```
"movlpd mytest_1(%rip),%xmm1 \n\t"
"movhpd mytest_1+8(%rip),%xmm1 \n\t"
```

These two instructions can be combined to one `movdqu`/`movdqa`, because x86 is a [*Little Endian*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) architecture

```
"movdqu mytest_1(%rip),%xmm1 \n\t"    // 16-byte unaligned or
"movdqa mytest_1(%rip),%xmm1 \n\t"    // for 16-byte aligned 'mytest_1'
```

Both can also be used for AVX 32-bit memory transfer ([`vmovdqu`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVDQU.html)/[`vmovdqa`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVDQA.html)):

```
"vmovdqu mytest_1(%rip),%ymm1 \n\t"   // 32-byte unaligned or
"vmovdqa mytest_1(%rip),%ymm1 \n\t"   // for 32-byte aligned 'mytest_1'
```

Regarding the second part of your question:

> I look for the reverse of Vmovdqa ymm1, mem256 source -> destination.

This does work in both directions, e.g. the possible instructions for `vmovdqa`:

```
VMOVDQA ymm1, ymm2/m256   RM   V/V   AVX   Move aligned packed integer values from ymm2/mem to ymm1.
VMOVDQA ymm2/m256, ymm1   MR   V/V   AVX   Move aligned packed integer values from ymm1 to ymm2/mem.
```

Comment: Thak you very much ! I just am triing to write a 128 Bit Multiplication using ymm registers and SSE2 technology. Maybe someone did it already?